# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chrome' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, selenium

I am having a bit of trouble with this - installed pip / the Webdriver & changed the path of it correctly to use selenium. And add the all the required packages
I cant find out what wrong i am did here, please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

```
def test_homePageTitle(self, setup):
    self.driver = setup
    self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
    act_title=self.driver.title
    self.driver.close()
    if act_title == "Your store.Login":
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
def test_Login(self, setup):
    self.driver = setup
    self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
    self.lp=LoginPage()
    self.lp.setUsername(self.username)
    self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
    self.lp.clickLogin()
    act_title = self.driver.title
    self.driver.close()
    if act_title == "Dashboard / nopCommerce administration":
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

my errors:
__________________________________________________________ Test_001_Login.test_homePageTitle __________________________________________________________

```
enter code here
```

self = <TestCases.Test_Login.Test_001_Login object at 0x000001AFCADABBB0>

```
def test_homePageTitle(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome
```

> ```
>   self.driver.get("https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin%2F")
> ```

E       AttributeError: type object 'Chrome' has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's webdriver is known to be buggy. I'd recommend you use a different library called Webdrivermanager along with selenium.

webdriver manager can be installed through pip in a virtualenv with
`pip install webdriver-manager` or in a conda environment with `conda install -c conda-forge webdriver-manager`

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

browser.get("https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin%2F")
```